# Need help to add a 3rd partition to external drive

Tags: catalina, disk-utility, partition, external-disk

so I have a WD external drive with 2 partitions and I'm trying to reclaim some space from one of the partitions and make a 3rd partition.  Im using disk utility.  Ive tried 3 times and I get the same message....   After the 1st attempt I reduced to the size to 1TB and lower and got the same message.  Is it possible to do this some other way and how?  Tks
[image: DU error]

what it shows before I attempt
[image: B4 attempt]

Comment: You can’t resize a partition with so little free space.  Back up your drive, wipe it clean, repartition it as you desire, then copy everything back.

Comment: Even though I have over 1 TB free?  I thought 2.91tb on the volume - 1.85 = 1.06 tb I could reclaim and add a new partition to use....

Comment: Free is a relative thing.  You may have it allocated to an existing partition but unused.  You need to have actual free, *un-allocated** space to create a partition in.

Comment: Ok. Tks. I’ll try that.

Comment: might there be a way to do this w/o having to move the files?  Problem - The back up files I have on the old partition are 1.85TB - I've deleted as much as I can.  The only other drive I have is a 2TB with is already partitioned 500gb ExFAT and 1.5 TB MAC.  Tks again.

Comment: You are rearranging the partitions on a drive which contain data.  This is risky so, you should have a backup anyway.  You don’t want to be making changes, make a small mistake then lose your work.

Comment: ok.  tks allan.  i have a related question on a 10tb drive im gonna post in superuser.  May I get your thoughts please?

Comment: post a link...and I'll take a look.

Comment: Allan - https://superuser.com/questions/1576701/partition-and-model-no-for-wd-drive/1576711#1576711.   Tks much!